# Install HTTPie on Windows

Tags: chocolatey, httpie

I installed HTTPie on Windows using Chocolatey. However, doing it this way installs Python to a default location (`C:\python312`) that I don't want it to use.

Is there a way to have Python install to another location when installing HTTPie via Chocolatey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Python](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/python312) package that Httpie depends on, it has an `/InstallDir` parameter (or, the non-metapackage does).

To use this, you would run something like `choco install python312 --params "/InstallDir:C:\your\install\path"`.

On running `choco install httpie`, Chocolatey should then resolve the dependency as already installed, and install Httpie.

In theory the Python package should also recognise existing installations of Python (of that version) and use that location, so simply preinstalling Python would also work.

Comment: I deleted the Python install added by Chocolatey and reinstalled it manually to somewhere sensible. I then had to force uninstall Httpie and reinstall it but it did then work using the pre-existing Python installation. So all good in the end.